# Exporting a cell structure from Matlab to Excel

Tags: arrays, excel, matlab, export-to-excel, matlab-struct

I have a cell structure which has <1*40 struct> inside it. Every structure has the same field names (each having 12 field names and respective values). I want to Export this cell Array into an Excel file such that all the field names become the heading (12 consecutive columns), and below each field Name Comes its respective field values.

I have tried xlswrite by using cell2struct but it does not help.
If anyone could help me with this ?

Comment: Can you post in some brief example data? Are you saying that you have a cell array that is 1 x 40 but every element contains a 1 x 1 struct?

Comment: @Suever yes. this is what i meant

Answer (score 1):

If your input data looks something like this:

```
data = {struct('a', 1, 'b', 2), struct('a', 3, 'b', 4)};
```

You can process it using a combination of [`struct2cell`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct2cell.html) and simple concatenation.

First convert from a cell array to an array of structs:

```
data = cat(2, data{:});
```

Then you can get the values using [`struct2cell`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct2cell.html)

```
values = struct2cell(data(:));
```

Then the column names should simply be the [`fieldnames`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fieldnames.html) of your struct

```
headers = fieldnames(data);
```

Then you can concatenate the headers with the data to yield the input to [`xlswrite`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlswrite.html)

```
xlsdata = cat(2, headers, values)'
xlswrite('filename.xlsx', xlsdata);

xlsdata =

    'a'    'b'
    [1]    [2]
    [3]    [4]
```

We can condense this a little bit:

```
xlsdata = cat(2, fieldnames(data{1}), struct2cell(cat(2, data{:})))';
xlswrite('filename.xlsx', xlsdata);
```